# Python copying defaultdict to dict with new order of key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a defaultdict with unsorted by key values:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
...
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2014-06-30': 2, '2013-04-18': 7, '2013-04-19': 9})
```

Sort list of keys:

```
tmp = sorted(d.keys())
```

And create new dict:

```
nd = {}
for i in tmp:
    nd[i] = d[i]
```

But as a result I am getting exact copy of source dict.
Although I added elements in new order.

Comment: you need an OrderedDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict  
ord_dict = OrderedDict()

for i in tmp:
    ord_dict[i] = d[i]
print(ord_dict)
OrderedDict([('2013-04-18', 7), ('2013-04-19', 9), ('2014-06-30', 2)])
```

Or as @jon Clements suggests simply:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems()))
```

Or `OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))` using python 3

Comment: `OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems()))` perhaps? Also wouldn't call it `ord` as that's a builtin function...

Comment: @JonClements, was just writing it and yep you right, changed ord.

Comment: Well, if you *really* wanted it to be 2.x/3.x cross-compatible, then `OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d))` but that's just getting a little bit ridiculous :)

Comment: @JonClements. I think I will keep it simple for now :)

Answer (score 3):

`dict` instances are arbitrarily ordered. If you want a specific order then use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Answer (score 0):

python dictionaries does not work that way. Dictionary is actually a hash map which means values are put in a spot in dict depending on key hash, not the order you put your item and when iterating, you will not get "ordered dict". Use OrderedDict class instead